# Яндекс не находит мета-тег description

Tags: html, seo, яндекс-вебмастер

На [странице](https://all-servs.com/view_portfolio/130) есть тег description: `<meta name="description" content="Аренда экскаватора hitachi 200">`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако в Яндекс.Вебмастер написано, что на этой странице тег `description` отсутствует. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Размер `description` должен быть в пределах 120-160 символов. У вас гораздо меньше. Исправьте и через некоторое время Яндекс подтянет изменения.

**P.S.** Ещё у вас непонятно зачем `vieport` два раза стоит.

**P.S.S** Еще на сайте висит загрузка `angular.map`, которая выдает `404`. Уберите загрузку на продакшене. Любая ошибка – это не очень хорошо для SEO.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: vieport  убрал спасибо, 404 не увидел нигде, в консоле посмотрел все ответы 200 ок

Comment: @heff добавил скриншот.